# Manage configured ipsec VPN with NetworkManager

Tags: network-manager, vpn, ipsec

I configured a strongswan VPN natively by editing `/etc/ipsec.conf` and `/etc/secrets.conf` under Ubuntu 18.04. I can now successfully establish the connections with:

```
sudo ipsec up profile
```

However, that is a bit inconvenient to use, especially, because there is no visual feedback showing when the connection is active.

The reason I could not directly configure the connection with NetworkManager is that the GUI for a strongswan connections does not expose any fields for EAP-TLS and I do not know if NetworkManager allows that.

How can I manage the working ipsec configuration with the NetworkManager GUI? Note that I have the NetworkManager packages for strongswan installed.

Answer (score 0):

strongSwan's NetworkManager plugin uses a completely different daemon (*charon-nm*) and configuration backend. There is no relationship between ipsec.conf or swanctl.conf based configurations (they could even be used concurrently).

So until somebody implements support EAP-TLS in the NetworkManager plugin/backend (see [#2097](https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/2097) on the strongSwan issue tracker) you will have to continue to use the command line tools.